# Cannot refresh reference to external xlsm file

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Excel files, parent and child, where child contains a library of functions used by parent's functions. For versioning purposes I keep them in the same folder and copy and rename the folder in exactly the same location to keep track of my versions. I also want the references to be dynamically updated so that when i move to a new version, parent always points to child in the same location.

So in order to accomplish this I have implemented two routines in parent.

One, is in ThisWorkbook I used Workbook_Open sub:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Force the location of the shared library to the current project folder irrespective where the project is located
    Call reloadSharedLibrary
End Sub
```

Two, in Modules.Libraries I added another sub reloadSharedLibrary:

```
Public librName As Variant


Public isRefReloaded As Boolean

Sub reloadSharedLibrary()

        isRefReloaded = True

        Dim VBAEditor As VBIDE.VBE
        Dim vbProj As VBIDE.VBProject
        Dim chkRef As VBIDE.Reference
        Dim BoolExists As Boolean
        Dim librPath As String

        Set VBAEditor = Application.VBE
        Set vbProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

        librName = "lib_emtm"
        librPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\lib.xlsm"

        ' delete any shared lib (if exists)
        For Each chkRef In vbProj.References
            If chkRef.Name = librName Then
                vbProj.References.Remove chkRef
                BoolExists = True
            End If
        Next

        ' you can only add it to VBAProject only after you quit the above loop
        On Error Resume Next
        vbProj.References.AddFromFile librPath

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "FATAR ERROR: Cannot find shared library file in project root": End
        End If


        Set vbProj = Nothing
        Set VBAEditor = Nothing

End Sub
```

Now, the problem with this is that when I copy the project folder to a new version folder the reference to child does not get updated. The child the version uses is from the old version.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, the procedure `reloadSharedLibrary` runs perfectly well but still the reference is unchanged?

Comment: Yeah, it does, no errors are thrown. I am changing the lib location from `H:\RISKMNGT\Modelling\MarketRisk\EMtM\01.development\03.model\v10` to `H:\RISKMNGT\Modelling\MarketRisk\EMtM\01.development\03.model\v10.AT_move_swaps`. Perhaps it doesnt like the new path?

Comment: I dont think so. My thoughts actually are on the whole process idea. I am thinking about it and have some doubts about its validity.

Comment: How did you verify that the referenced code is still from the old version?

Comment: When parent loads after this code execution, it also automatically opens child on the background. I simply go to File-information and see it's sitting in the old version folder

Comment: I dont think that's a proof of failure. It's likely because both workbooks have the same name so the editor failed to open the new one. However you should try to test which code the parent project actually references. You could also try to close all the workbooks (all Excel) and open again the parent and see if the editor still opens the old project.

Comment: @ASH, just tried to do what you are describing in your last sentence. No changes, still opening the old link. Plus I printed the path from references - it points to the old location.

Comment: One more question: where is the procedure `reloadSharedLibrary` located? in the parent or in the child?

Comment: both in parent. once they are called the reference should pull child and open on the background

Comment: Well if in parent, already remove the `AcctiveWorkbook` stuff and use `ThisWorkbook` instead. Wont solve the problem but already will narrow it. g2g now, will get back to this later if problem was not solved yet. I think what bothers the VBA runtime is that both projects have same name and lib-name, it seems to have consequences.

Comment: Replaced it with `ThisWorkbook`. Still the same problem...

Comment: I found the root of the problem and a solution to it, but cannot write it now. will be back to you in a few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the VBA project loads a document and its references, it assigns them a name, which is `lib_emtm` in your case. When you uncheck the reference to it, the reference is removed from the VBA project but the project editor will keep the name in its cache. This name will remain in the cache until you close the workbook and reopen it.

You can verify this in the project references menu: you will see that even if you uncheck the reference, the name of the library `lib_emtm` will still appear there.

Then when you try to add a reference to the "other" child workbook (the one in the same folder), the editor will find that the name is `lib_emtm` which is the same as the one in the cache, so instead of opening the new document and parsing it, it will use the cached version, which is the old one!

If you close then re-open the application, the name of the library will disappear from the cache, so you can install the correct version. To be complete, this pattern occurs only with references to other workbooks, not with regular `DLL`'s installed on the system.

I tried but couldn't find a VBA way to remove the `Cached library` from the editor's cache before re-installing it. If someone finds a way it would complete the solution. Therefore at the moment we must close the document before re-opening it and installing the lib. This process might be automated but I suggest a solution that prompts the user for that.

```
' Module ThisWorkbook
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Force the location of the shared library to the current project folder irrespective where the project is located
    Dim check As Boolean: check = checkSharedLibrary
    If check Then Exit Sub
    Dim prompt
    prompt = MsgBox("The installed lib_emtm library was uninstalled because it was not the correct version." & vbCrLf & _
            "If you click Ok, document will close and the correct version will be automatically installed when you reopen it." & vbCrLf & _
            "If you click Cancel, library will not be available in this session but will be installed next time you open the document", vbOKCancel)
    If prompt = vbOK Then ThisWorkbook.Close True
End Sub

' Regular module
Option Explicit
Private librName As String, librpath As String

' if correct version already installed (correct path) return true
' if library installed with incorrect version, uninstall it and return false
' if library not installed, install it and return true
Public Function checkSharedLibrary() As Boolean
    librName = "lib_emtm"
    librpath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\lib_emtm.xlsm"

    Dim chkRef As VBIDE.Reference
    For Each chkRef In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References
        If chkRef.name = librName Then Exit For
    Next

    If chkRef Is Nothing Then
        install_emtm
        checkSharedLibrary = True
    ElseIf Left(chkRef.FullPath, InStrRev(chkRef.FullPath, "\") - 1) = ThisWorkbook.Path Then
        checkSharedLibrary = True ' we have the correct version
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove chkRef ' return false
    End If
End Function

Private Sub install_emtm()
   On Error Resume Next
   ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile(librpath)
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "FATAR ERROR: Could not install lib_emtm:" & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
      "Please verify that the library's file is present in the same folder or try a manual install"
End Sub
```

A final remark, the process can be automated without user intervention if we close directly the application but before that we can *schedule* the re-opening of the workbook . But things might get complicated because the user may have other Excel documents open, so we cannot oblige her to close everything.

Comment: @ASH, a nice and simple solution. Thanks so much, really really appreciate!

Comment: @hardish you're always welcome. This question had me thinking for a while. Interesting :)